# Powershell setfocus when textbox is full

Tags: powershell, setfocus

Been doing a little bit of research on this and cant find a powershell answer, I need to change focus of one textbox to another when it is full. Example when inputting a phone number instead of having to press Tab after the area code it would shift focus to the next set. Below is what I have so far

```
`$Textbox9 = New-Object Systems.Windows.Forms.Textbox
 $Textbox9.MaxLength = 3
 $Textbox9.Location = '635,220'
 $Textbox9.Size = '40,20'
 $Textbox9.Name =
 $Textbox9.Text =
 $Form.Controls.Add($Textbox9)
 If ($Textbox9.Text.Length = 3){
     $Textbox10.SetFocus} `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register to the [TextChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. Once TextBox9 reached the max size it switches to Textbox10.

This should work:

```
$action = { if ($Textbox9.Text.Length -eq 3){
     $Textbox10.focus()} }
$Textbox9.Add_TextChanged($action)
```